# How to resize page to fit windows using meta viewport?

Tags: html, css, viewport, meta-tags, meta

How to resize page to fit windows using meta viewport ?
This is my code. i not show on jsfiddle because jsfiddle not approve to use meta tag.

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style>
-ms-@viewport {
    width: device-width;
    initial-scale: 1;
    zoom: 1;
    min-zoom: 1;
    max-zoom: 3;
    user-zoom: fixed;
}
@viewport {
    width: device-width;
    initial-scale: 1;
    zoom: 1;
    min-zoom: 1;
    max-zoom: 3;
    user-zoom: fixed;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="overflow:hidden; margin:0">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content" style=" text-align: center; ">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vgz0PDe.png">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vgz0PDe.png">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vgz0PDe.png">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vgz0PDe.png">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vgz0PDe.png">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vgz0PDe.png">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vgz0PDe.png">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vgz0PDe.png">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vgz0PDe.png">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vgz0PDe.png">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vgz0PDe.png">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vgz0PDe.png">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vgz0PDe.png">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vgz0PDe.png">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vgz0PDe.png">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vgz0PDe.png">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vgz0PDe.png">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vgz0PDe.png">
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When i test on 1280 x 800 px resolution it's show 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2mW9.png

And then i test on 800 x 600 px resolution it's show 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuPUA.png

But on 800 x 600 px resolution i want to show
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1KSR.png

How can i do with meta viewport ?

Comment: You can't use media queries?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe you want a fixed viewport width of 800px if you want to keep it looking the same but just scaled. From memory this can cause some inconsistent behavior on some browsers/devices so a pure CSS approach such as media queries (as Mr Lister suggested is usually a much better solution)

If you want to try setting the viewport width can be done by setting the width attribute on your viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=800, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```